# How to use the apply function in R where function requires the column name and values in the same column for the functions arguments?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, switch-statement, apply

I would like to create a function such that for a certain data frame, it is able to use the column name as the first argument of a function, and use the values of a column (row values of a particular column) as the second argument in a function. The values of the second argument will then be converted to a numerical value based on values set in a switch function.

Here is what I have been working on so far.

```
# I also put print("ERROR in Question")) if there is no match at all
scoreraw <- function(Question, Answer) {

  switch(Question, "Today is my favourite day?" = 
  {switch(Answer,"Strongly Agree" = 3,"Agree"= 2, "Disagree" = 1, "Strongly 
Disagree" = 0)}, 
   "I hate Tuesdays?"= 
  {switch(Answer,"Strongly Agree" = 0,"Agree"= 1, "Disagree" = 2, "Strongly 
Disagree" = 3)}, 
   print("ERROR in Question"))
}
```

Here is a quick test with the function to demonstrate how it works:

```
# We expect the value to be 3 based on the Question and Answer argument
scoreraw("Today is my favourite day?","Strongly Agree")
    # [1] 3



#Let us now create a dummy dataset of questions

x <- c("Strongly Agree","Agree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree")
y <- c("Strongly Agree","Agree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree")

c <- data.frame(x,y)

# Just changing the names to match the questions in the switch statement
colnames(c) <- c("Today is my favourite day?", "I hate Tuesdays?")

# The two factors were converted to characters since factors are treated as 
# integers by default (I may be incorrect here)
c$`Today is my favourite day?` <- as.character(c$`Today is my favourite day`)
c$`I hate Tuesdays?` <- as.character(c$`I hate Tuesdays`)

#>c
# Today is my favourite day?    I hate Tuesdays?
# 1             Strongly Agree    Strongly Agree
# 2                      Agree             Agree
# 3                   Disagree          Disagree
# 4          Strongly Disagree Strongly Disagree
```

This is what I want the dataframe to look like after applying my function

```
#  Today is my favourite day? I hate Tuesdays?
# 1                          3                0
# 2                          2                1
# 3                          1                2
# 4                          0                3
```

I tried to use the apply function but my issue is how to select an arbitrary column name and apply the function to all row values in a particular column? .At the moment I can only apply the function by manually selected the column name and a certain row value.

```
#Example of selecting column name and row value manually
scoreraw(colnames(c)[2],c[1,2])
# [1] 0
```

## EDIT current working code without ability to select arbitrary columns

```
# I also put print("ERROR in Question")) if there is no match at all
scoreraw <- function(Question, Answer) {

  switch(Question, "Today is my favourite day?" = 
  {switch(Answer,"Strongly Agree" = 3,"Agree"= 2, "Disagree" = 1, "Strongly 
Disagree" = 0)}, 
  "I hate Tuesdays?"= 
  {switch(Answer,"Strongly Agree" = 0,"Agree"= 1, "Disagree" = 2, "Strongly 
Disagree" = 3)}, 
   print("ERROR in Question"))
 }


 #Let us now create a dummy dataset of questions

x <- c("Strongly Agree","Agree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree")
y <- c("Strongly Agree","Agree","Disagree","Strongly Disagree")

c <- data.frame(x,y)

# Just changing the names to match the questions in the switch statement
colnames(c) <- c("Today is my favourite day?", "I hate Tuesdays?")

# The two factors were converted to characters since factors are treated as 
# integers by default (I may be incorrect here)
c$`Today is my favourite day?` <- as.character(c$`Today is my favourite 
day`)
c$`I hate Tuesdays?` <- as.character(c$`I hate Tuesdays`)



call_scoreraw <- function(n, DF) {
  sapply(DF[[n]], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[n], x))
}

#I included unlist as I noticed the output can also be a list
a <- unlist(call_scoreraw(1, c))
b <- as.data.frame(a)
```

I am now trying to incorporate a For loop in the `call_scoreraw` function to apply the `scoreraw` function to any column/s.

```
call_scoreraw <- function(n, DF) {
  Storage <- numeric(ncol(DF))
  for (i in n:ncol(DF)){
  Storage[i] <- sapply(DF[,i], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[i], x))
  }
}
```

As you can see, I currently need to find a way to store the values from the for loop. I am not able to do this using the defined storage variable `Storage` Any suggestions for how I can do this?

Comment: There is a typo in the function `scoreraw`, it should be `Tuesdays` not `tuesdays`.

Comment: Thanks I have changed the typo now. @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define another function to call `scoreraw`. Like this:

```
call_scoreraw <- function(n, DF) {
    if(length(n) > 1){
        t(sapply(n, function(i){
            sapply(DF[[i]], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[i], x))
        }))
    } else {
        sapply(DF[[n]], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[n], x))
    }
}

call_scoreraw(2, c)
#   Strongly Agree             Agree          Disagree Strongly Disagree 
#                0                 1                 2                 3

call_scoreraw(1:2, c)
#     Strongly Agree Agree Disagree Strongly Disagree
#[1,]              3     2        1                 0
#[2,]              0     1        2                 3
```

Note that the call with a vector of values `n` returns an object of class `matrix` that you can coerce to `data.frame` if you want to.

```
res <- call_scoreraw(1:2, c)
res2 <- as.data.frame(res)
```

Comment: What about if you want to apply this call_scoreraw function to an arbiturary number of columns? - I would like to automate this function such that I do not need to manually index the column I would like to select. In other words an implicit FOR loop. @RuiBarradas

Comment: I tried out the code and it is working well. For my own learning,could you perhaps explain this part of the code    `t(sapply(n, function(i){
            sapply(DF[[i]], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[i], x))
        }))`         I would like to understand the reason for embedding the second`sapply` function within the `function(i)`  i.e. this part  ... `function(i){
            sapply(DF[[i]], function(x) scoreraw(colnames(DF)[i], x))
        }))`

Comment: @MrReference The first `sapply` loops through the vector `n` and the second one through the vector `DF[[i]]`. So, for each `i` in `n` and for each `x` in `DF[[i]]` apply function `scoreraw`, that takes two arguments, a column name and a scalar.